# Webpack inside a docker container "can't resolve './src'"

Tags: docker, webpack

I'm trying to run a one-off webpack from within a docker container to generate a single bundle file. Unfortunately, webpack won't run inside the container based on the image I've configured.

`Dockerfile` ("DockerfileBuild"):

```
FROM node:10-alpine

COPY package.json ./

RUN npm install

RUN ["npm", "run", "build"]
```

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  dist:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: DockerfileBuild
```

If I run `docker-compose up dist` I get `ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src' in '/'`.

I assume I haven't set up my image properly, but at this point I don't know what to do.

Notes:

- The `npm install` seems to run ok beforehand.
- The bundling runs ok outside the container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have your actual source files copied inside of the container before running `npm run`. I assume you have some reference to `./src` in `package.json`, which would explain such an error.

Try copying everything you need before the `RUN` command (you can start copying everything with `COPY . .`, but may want to copy only `./src`, that's on you).

```
FROM node:10-alpine

COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install

COPY . .
RUN ["npm", "run", "build"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since version 4.0.0, webpack doesn't need a configuration file and the default entry point is './src/index.js'. Based on the error that you are getting, it looks like you are not copying webpack.config.js into the docker image. It is trying to find the default index.js file in the './src' folder and that is why you are getting this error. If you copy the webpack.config.js then it should work.